# How to combine two Ajax and PHP code for lazy load and filter by category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used this ajax PHP code for lazy load and filter according to category, i want to combine both of them because lazy load works on first load but doesnt work with category buttons.

My AJAX code sends limit and start values to `fetch.php` and fetch data in the division
A 2nd ajax code sends cat_id to `load-prod.php` to filter data on button click

```
index.php

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 p-3 text-center">
<span>Categories&nbsp&nbsp</span>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark active showct" value="">All</button>
<?php echo show_cat(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4" id="showpr">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center p-3" id="datamsg"></div>
</div>
//lazy load
<script>
var limit = 9; //The number of records to display per request
var start = 0; //The starting pointer of the data
var action = 'inactive'; //Check if current action is going on or not. If not then inactive otherwise active
 function lazyload(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#showpr').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#datamsg').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-dark' disabled>No more data</button>");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#datamsg').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-dark' disabled>Loading More...</button>");
     action = 'inactive';
    } }});}

if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  lazyload(limit, start);
 }

 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && action== "inactive")
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    lazyload(limit, start);
   }, 1000);}});
</script>

//show according to category
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.showct').click(function(){
var cat_id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url:"load-prod.php",
method:"POST",
data:{cat_id:cat_id},
success:function(data){
$("#showpr").html(data);
}});
});});
</script>
```

```
load-prod.php

<?php
include ('connect.php');
global $con;
if(isset($_POST["cat_id"]))
{
    if($_POST["cat_id"]!='')
    {
        $cf = "select * from products where c_id = '".$_POST['cat_id']."'";
    }
    else{
        $cf = "select * from products";
    }
    $filter = mysqli_query($con,$cf);
    while ($ctf=mysqli_fetch_array($filter)) {
        echo "<div class='col-12'><h5 class='card-title'>".$ctf['name']."</h5>";
    }
}
?>
```

```
fetch.php

<?php
include ('connect.php');
global $con;

if(isset($_POST["limit"], $_POST["start"]))
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM album ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ".$_POST["start"].", ".$_POST["limit"]."";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<div class='col-12'><h5 class='card-title'>".$row['name']."</h5>" ;
 }
}?>
```